# Quiver plot / Vector Field in Plotly.js?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I'm looking at the [scientific charts](https://plotly.com/javascript/scientific-charts/) section of the Plotly.js gallery but there's no option for quiver / vector field like there is in the Python version. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: It has been on the wishlist for a while (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2221). If you look at the python code, you can see that the quiver chart is built as a scatter chart internally (https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/03979d105c65dda3df3a155322eaff18f203b03f/packages/python/plotly/plotly/figure_factory/_quiver.py#L111).